# MySQL gives to many values back

Tags: mysql, database

I have a MariaDB Database.

```
    #Create table room
create table if not exists room
(
  pk_roomNumber   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  roomdescription VARCHAR(50),
  netmask         VARCHAR(15),
  subnetmask      VARCHAR(15)
);

#Create table client
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS client
(
  pk_macaddr       VARCHAR(17) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  ipadress         VARCHAR(15),
  hostname         VARCHAR(50),
  fk_pk_roomnumber INTEGER,
  last_seen        DATE,
  is_online        BOOLEAN
);


ALTER table client
  ADD CONSTRAINT pk_fk_roomnumber
    FOREIGN KEY fk_pk_roomnumber (fk_pk_roomnumber)
      REFERENCES room (pk_roomNumber);
```

And I am trying to find every client which is in the room 131.

I am currently trying it with this query

```
select hostname, pk_macaddr, ipadress, roomdescription, fk_pk_roomnumber from client,room
WHERE fk_pk_roomnumber AND fk_pk_roomnumber = '131';
```

I have 160 clients in my Database, i splitted them to 4 rooms 40 clients each but when I start my query I get all 160 clients. Where is my query wrong ?

Regards,
Lukas

Comment: this doesnt look right: WHERE fk_pk_roomnumber AND

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a wrong join condition: in your code you are not joining the two tables.

```
select c.hostname, c.pk_macaddr, c.ipadress, r.roomdescription, r.fk_pk_roomnumber 
from client c
INNER JOIN room r ON c.fk_pk_roomnumber =  r.pk_roomnumber
  and r.pk_roomnumber  = '131';
```

And you should use explicit join syntax (and not old and unclear implicit join syntax based on where).

Answer (score 0):

You want to "join" client and room tables:

```
select client.hostname, client.pk_macaddr, client.ipadress, room.roomdescription, client.fk_pk_roomnumber 
from client
inner join room
on client.fk_pk_roomnumber = room.pk_roomnumber
where room.pk_roomnumber = '131';
```